# WebBrowser control not run jquery with Windows Embedded Handheld

Tags: jquery, webbrowser-control, windows-embedded-compact

A simple form application with a WebBrowser control does not execute jquery scripts, while IE on same device works. My environment is a Pocket PC with Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Classic, CE OS 5.2. Are there some tricks to make WebBrowser control have the same behaviour of local IE? Does WebBrowser behavior depend from developing platform project properties (VS2008)? Some help links are welcome too.

Answer (score -1):

At last I can answer by myself. I have checked OS versions with attention and I discovered some mess, so I suggest to do the same before getting mad. Yes, WebBrowser behaviour strictly depends from development platform properties.